# Rabl and doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rabl

I develop api for my rails project and don't now how to solve this problem

I use `doorkeeper` gem for authentication and `rabl` gem for json rendering. And i have to add some fields **only** for logged user.

For example: part of `show.rabl`:

```
node :accessible, if: lambda { |m| current_user } do |model|
  model.accessible(current_user)
end
```

And `api/application_controller.rb`:

```
def current_user
  User.find(doorkeper_token.resource_owner_id) if doorkeper_token
end
```

I also tried this way (`rabl` file) :

```
if current_user
   node(:accessible) { |m| m.accessible(current_user) }
else
   {no: "no"} # this line rendered!!
end
```

And rabl doesn't know anything about my method and return false in `if` lambda.
How can i solve this problem? i ready for any suggestions. Thank you!

i use `rails-3.2.6 doorkeeper-0.4.2 rabl-0.6.13`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

- setting an instance variable in your controller instead of using `current_user`
- or rendering a different file wether the user is logged in or not (and use rabl partial to avoid duplication)

I'm also using rabl and doorkeeper so keep me up to date if you find a good solution ;) I might need to do the same soon.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i don't need help now. It was my mistake;) i forgot `access_token` in my params and `doorkeper_token` was not initialized, that's why there wasn't `current_user`.
But i can add, this method works very well ;)